# Width of the bar in Jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

Is there a way to adjust the width of the bars in a Barchart?

I create my chart with the following code.

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Report", // chart title
                "Date", // domain axis label
                "Number", // range axis label
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                true, // include legend
                true, // tooltips?
                false // URLs?
                );
```

Answer (score 24):

You can also set the maximum width of a bar. This is useful if you have a wide chart but occasionally there are only one or two data points and you don't want a single big fat bar taking up the whole area.

```
CategoryPlot categoryPlot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
BarRenderer br = (BarRenderer) categoryPlot.getRenderer();
br.setMaximumBarWidth(.35); // set maximum width to 35% of chart
```

Answer (score 10):

You can't directly specify the width of the bars, but there's a few attributes that can be changed which affect the width. You should take a look at the ***lowerMargin***, ***upperMargin*** and ***categoryMargin*** attributes defined by the CategoryAxis or the ***itemMargin*** attribute in the BarRenderer.

For example:

```
    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
    renderer.setItemMargin(.1);
```

The double specified in `setItemMargin(double percent)` is the percentage of the overall length of the category axis that will be used for the space between the bars within the same category (default is .2 or 20%). The smaller this value is, the larger the bars will be.

Answer (score 9):

After getting no results using positive margins and zero, I tried using negative numbers for `itemMargin` to see what would happen. The bars started getting thicker. I don't know if this is recommended, though, since you will get overlap if there is not enough space available.

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
renderer.setItemMargin(-2);
```

Comment: Brilliant. I'm having the same problem again and I couldn't achieve anything with setMaximumBarWidth, this did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

According to Dave Gilbert (JFreeChart Project Leader)

> The bar widths are automatically
>   calculated and will depend on the
>   chart or plot width and the number of
>   items in your dataset.

See the discussion [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27306).