# Reduce the width of the bar graph in java

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

I am using JFreeChart for displaying Bar Graph, the width of the bars in the graph is huge. I want to reduce the width of the bars, is there any API for it, please let me know..

Answer (score -1):

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
renderer.setItemMargin(-2);
```

Try the above code. Try to look at this thread as well.

[Width of the bar in Jfreechart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973936/width-of-the-bar-in-jfreechart)

Please note above snippet is from same thread.

As an answer to your comment following is the Java Doc for the same method

```
public void setItemMargin(double percent)
Sets the item margin and sends a RendererChangeEvent to all registered listeners. The value is expressed as a percentage of the available width for plotting all the bars, with the resulting amount to be distributed between all the bars evenly.
Parameters:
percent - the margin (where 0.10 is ten percent).
```

Comment: yes I tried it but it doesn't work with renderer.setItemMargin(-2); with this code the bars just get disappeared but when I changed it to  renderer.setItemMargin(.10); its done the size got reduced by half. I want to know what the parameter of this method do?

Comment: BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer(); renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(.10); This line of code solved my problem.